# Access to Zurb Foundation for Apps modules in AngularJS App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zurb-foundation

I am working on an AngularJS app using Foundation for Apps. In my layout, I am using a Foundation Apps panel for the top-menu

```
<div zf-panel="" id="topMenu" position="top" class="panel-fixed">...</div>
```

I would like to cleanly access the state of the panel in my AngularJS app. I went through the documentation [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/docs/#!/angular-modules) and the best thing I could do is to be alerted when the state changes ("toggle", "open" or "close"), in my app.js:

```
.run([
    '$rootScope',
    'FoundationApi',
    function ($rootScope, FoundationApi) {
        FoundationApi.subscribe('topMenu', function(event) {
            console.log(event);
        })
    }
]);
```

In Ng-Inspector I can see the Panel module (zfPanel) under the $rootScope, with a boolean property named "active", but the only way I could access it so far is this:

```
$rootScope.menuClosed = true;
FoundationApi.subscribe('topMenu', function(event) {
    $rootScope.menuClosed = angular.element('#topMenu').isolateScope().active;
})
```

I'd like to connect to the Foundation Apps modules in other parts of the app, is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I found a clean way to use the Foundation API event without calling isolateScope on the DOM element:

```
    FoundationApi.subscribe('topMenu', function(event) {
        if (event === 'close') {
            $rootScope.menuClosed = true;
        } else if (event === 'open') {
            $rootScope.menuClosed = false;
        } else { 
            // event === 'toggle'
            $rootScope.menuClosed = !$rootScope.menuClosed;
        };
    })
```